# Function that returns a function setting property on existing object. JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to be able to generate a dynamic property on objects and I have tried doing this by creating a function that takes an input object to then return a function that takes a parameter. This parameter is used to set the dynamic property.

My issue is that once the function is created, I don't seem to be getting a new object each time and instead the function is setting the property on a previously assigned object.

I have tried re-working the assigning of an object but to no avail, I have tested out alternative (less ideal code) which works but I want to know why my initial solution does not work.

```js
/* Returns a function which will assign a 'required' property to all objects within the given object */
const generateSchemaField = obj => {
 obj = Object.assign({}, obj);
 return function(required = false) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
   Object.assign(obj[key], {
    required,
   });
  });
  return obj;
 };
};

/* The way the above function would be invoked*/
const userEmailUsingGenerateSchemaField = generateSchemaField({
 user_email: {
  type: 'string',
  description: 'A user email',
 },
});


/* The below function does not encounter the same problem */
const userEmailNotUsingGenerateSchemaField = function(required = false) {
 let obj = {
  user_email: {
   type: 'string',
   description: 'A user email',
  },
 };
 Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  Object.assign(obj[key], {
   required,
  });
 });
 return obj;
}; 

let firstResultUsing = userEmailUsingGenerateSchemaField();
let secondResultUsing = userEmailUsingGenerateSchemaField(true);

console.log(firstResultUsing);
console.log(secondResultUsing);
```

Expected Output

```
{
  user_email: { type: 'string', description: 'A user email', required: false }
}
{
  user_email: { type: 'string', description: 'A user email', required: true }
}
```

Actual

```
{
  user_email: { type: 'string', description: 'A user email', required: true }
}
{
  user_email: { type: 'string', description: 'A user email', required: true }
}
```

Comment: because you use the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Story**

It's a simple issue of referencing the same object.

To prove this compare the two objects

```js
console.log(firstResultUsing === secondResultUsing)
```

You'll see that it prints `true` which proves that they are both referencing the same object.

Scroll down for solution!

**Long Story**

At this line:

```
const userEmailUsingGenerateSchemaField = generateSchemaField({
  user_email: {
    type: 'string',
    description: 'A user email',
  },
})
```

What's happening here is that your `generateSchemaField` function is returning a function which has a **closure** over `obj` which is nothing but

```
{
  user_email: {
    type: 'string',
    description: 'A user email',
  },
}
```

Now at this line:

```
const firstResultUsing = userEmailUsingGenerateSchemaField()
```

The function gets evaluated and returns the modified object

```
{
  user_email: {
    type: 'string',
    description: 'A user email',
    required: false
  },
}
```

Remember the returned object still has the same reference as `obj`

Now again at line:

```
const secondResultUsing = userEmailUsingGenerateSchemaField(true)
```

What's happening here is the same referenced `obj` object is modified and it's updated with the property `required: true`

That's why when you `console.log` both are showing `required: true` because they both reference the same object.

**Solution**

```
const generateSchemaField = obj => {
  return function(required = false) {
    const objClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    Object.keys(objClone).forEach(key => {
      Object.assign(objClone[key], {
        required,
      });
    });
    return objClone;
  };
};
```

Let's break this down.
I removed `obj = Object.assign({}, obj);` as it doesn't do any good. It seems a redundant line.

Next, I did a **deep clone** of the `obj`. Remember `Object.assign` will not work as it just creates a **shallow copy/clone** and here it won't work as the key `email_id` holds a reference to an object.
Beware that deep cloning using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` will work only for objects that have JSON-safe values(No functions or `undefined` etc...).

Then, I am manipulating this cloned object and returning it.
Now there is no threat of manipulating the same referenced object.

Let me know if this helps or you need a better explanation.

Comment: Great explanation. Have you got any ideas as to how I could keep the same code style but not encounter this issue? Other than repeating userEmailNotUsingGenerateSchemaField method everywhere?

Comment: Thank you, I did not realise object.assign was creating shallow copies. This makes more sense. Will mark accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You call `generateSchemaField` only *once* when you do

```
const userEmailUsingGenerateSchemaField = generateSchemaField({
    user_email: {
        type: 'string',
        description: 'A user email',
    },
});
```

So, when if you invoke the function it returns multiple times, you would still be using the same object `obj` captured by the closure generated by `generateSchemaField`

If you want to keep your code mostly the same, need to do the cloning of the object (`obj = Object.assign({}, obj);` in your code) inside the *inner* function, then you will be generating a fresh copy of the object each invocation. However, be aware that that only does a *shallow* copy, so even though you clone an object with `Object.assign`, any objects that are properties of it would still be shared between each clone:

```js
const obj = { 
  foo: 1, 
  subObj: { bar : 2 }
}

const a = Object.assign({}, obj);
const b = Object.assign({}, obj);

//this is not shared
a.foo += "a";
b.foo += "b";

//so changes in the cloned objects remain there
console.log("obj.foo", obj.foo);
console.log("a.foo", a.foo);
console.log("b.foo", b.foo);

//this object is shared
a.subObj.bar += "a";
b.subObj.bar += "b";

//so changes affect all of them
console.log("obj.subObj.bar", obj.subObj.bar);
console.log("a.subObj.bar", a.subObj.bar);
console.log("b.subObj.bar", b.subObj.bar);
```

You need to do some form of [deep clone mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/10916838) to avoid that. I will use [`cloneDeep` from Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) to illustrate this:

```js
/* Returns a function which will assign a 'required' property to all objects within the given object */
const generateSchemaField = obj => {
  return function(required = false) {
    //make a fresh copy
    const result = _.cloneDeep(obj);
    Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
      Object.assign(result[key], {
        required,
      });
    });
    return result;
  };
};

/* The way the above function would be invoked*/
const userEmailUsingGenerateSchemaField = generateSchemaField({
  user_email: {
    type: 'string',
    description: 'A user email',
  },
});

let firstResultUsing = userEmailUsingGenerateSchemaField();
let secondResultUsing = userEmailUsingGenerateSchemaField(true);

console.log(firstResultUsing);
console.log(secondResultUsing);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can check the link for deep cloning for other methods to deep clone, if you don't want to use Lodash.